# Invariant for Hoare-Logic on RandomSearch

Tags: loop-invariant, hoare-logic

I'm trying to proof the following RandomSeach-Algorithm and to figure out the invariant for the loop.

Since the function `randomIndex(..)` creates a random number I cannot use an invariant like

```
 ≥ 0 ∧  <  − 1 ⇒ [] ≠ e
```

. That means, all elements between 0 and i-1, with i is the index of the current checked element, is not the searched element.

So I thought I define a hypothetical sequence `r`, that contains all elements that have already been compared to the searched value or are going to be compared to the searched value. Thats why it is just a hypothetical sequence, because I actually do not know the elements that are going to be compared to the searched value until they have been realy compared.

That means it applies `r.lenght() ≤ runs`  and in the case the searched element was found

```
(r[r.lenght()-1] = value) ↔ (r[currentRun] = value).
```

Then I can define a invariant like:

```
 ≥ 0 ∧  < currentRun  ⇒ r[] ≠ e
```

Can I do this, because the sequence r is not real? It does not feel right. Does anyone have a diffrent idea for an invariant?

The program:

```
public boolean RandomSearch (int value, int[] f, int runs) {
    int currentRun = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    while (currentRun < runs || !found) {
        int x = randomIndex(0, n-1)
        if (value == f[x]) {
            found = true;
        }
        currentRun = currentRun + 1;
    }//end while
    return found;
}//end RandomSearch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I use following invariant

```
currentRun <= runs & f.length > 0
```

Than I can proof the algorithm :)